# When does the lighting hit the clock tower so Marty 1 goes back to 1985 while Marty 2 burns the almanac and learns Doc is in 1885?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

In *Back to the Future II*, Marty and Doc go back to 1955 to get the sports almanac from Biff to save the future while trying to avoid their younger selves. When they succeed they burn it while the storm is brewing. Marty 1 goes back to 1985, then Doc 2 goes to 1885 and Marty knows by a letter, then goes to the Doc of 1955 after Marty 1 goes back to 1985 and the Doc faints.

So I'm confused.  When does the lighting hit the clock tower so Marty 1 goes back to 1985 while Marty 2 burns the almanac and learns Doc is in 1885?

Comment: *"When does the lighting hit the clock tower"* It hits the clock tower at the same (local) time in both *BttF* ***&*** *BttF II*. I don't understand what it is about that, that you find confusing!

Comment: im asking when does marty 1 goes back to 1985 while marty 2 burns the almanac

Comment: 10:04 pm, November 12, 1955 on the (Saturday) night of the *Enchantment Under The Sea* dance.

Comment: oh ok but i meant when is marty 2 burning the almanac and learning of doc in 1885 while marty 1 goes back to 1985 when the lighting hits the clocktower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The timing of exactly when Marty 2 burns the almanac compared to when Marty 1 is sent back to 1985 isn't clear,  but it looks like burning the almanac happens before the lightning strike.**

Here's the order of events

1. Marty 2 burns the almanac
2. Doc 2 is sent back to 1885
3. Marty 2 receives Doc 2's letter
4. Marty 2 runs to the clock tower to find Doc 1, arriving just after Marty 1 returns to 1985.

You could get accurate time up to when Marty 2 says;

> There's only one person who could help me now

But after that it's unclear how long it took him to run from where he burned the almanac to the clock tower.

Comment: So Marty 2 burns the book before Marty  1 goes back to 1985 ?  how

Comment: Why do you think he couldn't?

Comment: im not sure thats why im asking

Comment: From Marty 2's perspective, what Marty 1 is doing is in his past. The fact that they are occurring at the same time to an outside observer doesn't matter.